# I'm looking for a word, or a phrase that would describe someone's outlook and position

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, phrase-meaning, expression-choice

I'm looking for a word, or a phrase that would describe someone's opinion, position, attitude towards some idea or outlook.

EXAMPLE: Let's say you are talking about a travel plan with your friends, and you guys have plan A, plan B and plan C. You've expressed your opinion about the plan A and you said you like it more than the other plans, someone says he likes plan B, another friend says she likes plan C, so your opinions are different.

Now you are becoming more pushy, trying to explain why you like Plan A and start insisting, that everybody should consider plan A, because it's the safest travel plan.

Can you say - I am inclined to plan A?

Comment: My mind is set on plan A. http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-set-on-upon-sth

Comment: You could say *I prefer Plan A.* Or *I like Plan A the best.* Not sure where the "more pushy" part comes in. If you want to persuade others, talk about the plan's advantages, not about your preferences.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you are [***advocating***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/advocate) plan A.

> Publicly recommend or support.
> *‘voters supported candidates who advocated an Assembly’*

Reference:
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/advocate

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to ***sell*** Plan A to the others.

M-W:

> ***[sell](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sell)***
>   *verb*
>
> **5a** :  to develop a belief in the truth, value, or desirability of :  gain acceptance for
>
> As in: trying to ***sell*** a program to the Congress